# maximize function with two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization

I would like to maximize the function:

$f(x,y) = c[x\log(2y) + (1-x)\log(2(1-y))]$ subject to constraint that $x,y \in (0,1)$

to find a relationship between $x$ and $y$ that maximizes $f(x,y)$. My solution is: take partial derivative with respect to $y$ and set to 0:

$\partial f/\partial y = c\times\partial/\partial y[x\log(2y) + (1-x)\log(2(1-y))] = 0$

I treat $x$ as constant and I believe this yields that: $x = y$, for the derivative to be zero. Questions:

1. Is this the correct way to solve this, and how can we show $x = y$ is a maximum?
2. I think the $2$ constant inside the $\log$ doesn't change the solution. If we had substituted any constant $z$ for $2$ in the equation, ie:

$f(x,y) = c[x\log(zy) + (1-x)\log(z(1-y))]$

The result would be the same. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, look at the convexity of the function at the extremum.

For the second part of the question : if we consider $$F = c\Big(x\log(zy) + (1-x)\log(z(1-y))\Big)= c\Big(x\log(y) + (1-x)\log((1-y))+\log(z)\Big)$$ I suppose that we can forget $c$ and $z$ as long as we search for extremum conditions (I assume $c\neq 0$ and $z\neq 0$) . So, the critical points do not depend on $c$ or $z$.

Now, if we compute the partials, we have $$F'_x=\log (y z)-\log ((1-y) z)=\log (y )-\log (1-y)$$ $$F'_y=\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1-x}{1-y}$$ Setting the first equal to $0$ leads to $y=\frac{1}{2}$ and replacing in the second it cancels for $x==\frac{1}{2}$ too.

This just to confirm that you are totally right. It is very good you notice points like this one.